# What is the purpose of PyJWT encryption argument?

Tags: python, pyjwt

I'm new using the JWT on web-apps.
I'm not sure what info should be stored in a JWT, but in my case, I'm saving sensitive user data, such as e-mail and username. I wish to safely secure this info on my JWT.

Using the `pyjwt` module, I was able to successfully create my tokens. Here is an example of how I've been using it.

```py
import jwt
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

data = {
    "user": {}, # Here I would fill with my user data.
    "exp": datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=2)
}
jwt.encode(data,"my-super-secret-key", "HS256")
```

This code above, returns a token where I thought it was encrypted.

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyIjp7fSwiZXhwIjoxNjMwMzAxMjI4fQ.sF3NeOArV5Mkgz9oemNMA4-RPF-mXKCIkQrlMQPLMV4
```

Using the https://jwt.io/ JWT checker, I found out that my token was actually being "decrypted" without the use of `my-super-secret-key`. This made me wonder what was the purpose of the secret key in PyJWT anyways. My guess is that it's just for signing the token.

And how can I actually secure my JWT token? (I've read about JWE, but didn't quite understood it yet, would really appreciate a concise explanation)

Comment: A **JWT** is a token (some kind of data) that is **signed**, and the recipient is been able to prove the signature. What you need is an encrypted version that is named **JWE**. Your Python library does not seem to support JWE's so you need to change the lib. On https://jwt.io/ you find a lot of libs that support JWE's, for my cross-platform project I have choosen **authlib** (https://github.com/lepture/authlib). A sample code is here (disclaimer: I'm the author): https://github.com/java-crypto/cross_platform_crypto/blob/main/JwtJweRsaOaep256Encryption/JweRsaOaep256Encryption.py

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response! I've read about JWE, but I'm struggling with the encryption algorithms. I'm gonna dig into encryption algorithms so I can understand how to properly encode my data! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A JWT consist of three sections: header, payload and signature. All tree sections will be BASE64 **encoded**. They are **not encrypted**.

The `algorithm` argument to [`jwt.encode()`](https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#jwt.encode) defines the algorithm used to **sign** the token. This will prove that the token is authentic and prevent manipulation by the user and a third party.

You can choose within a set of symmetric and asymmetric algorithms:

Symmetric algorithm will create shorter signatures but require a better protection of the key since it has to be stored on every machine involved in issuing and verifying the token.

Asymmetric algorithms will create long signatures, require at least a minimal PKI, but you need to distribute a public key only. The private key remains on the system issuing the tokens.

Comment: Thanks! I'm gonna read more about asymmetric algorithms and try to implement the JWE token! Signing the token is a good option but in my case I need that data encrypted! Thanks for the response!